# toLocaleString adding custom letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this code below I need to render time looking like this **3h15m**. Now it's just **3:15**. How can I add endings to hours and minutes? Thank you in advance.

```
<span className={s.data}>{new Date(ticket.segments[0].duration)
  .toLocaleString('en', { hour: 'numeric',
                        minute: 'numeric' })}</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```js
let [, hh, mm] = new Date(2020, 07, 12, 15, 30, 0)
  .toLocaleString('en', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric'
  }).match(/(\d{1,2})\:(\d{2})/)
console.log(`${hh}h${mm}m`)
```

Comment: better late than never :) Thanks for the answer!